# How does this python loop check for primality, if it loops less than the number n?

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes

Hi guys so I was wondering how is this code:

```
def is_prime(n):
    for i in range(2, int(n**.5 + 1)):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

able to check for prime when on line 2: `for i in range(2, int(n**.5 + 1)):` the range is not : `range(2, n)`? Shouldn't it have to iterate through every number till `n` but excluding it? This one is not doing that but somehow it works... Could someone explain why it works please.

Comment: This is not anything Python. This is pure **maths**. A composite number must have a factor less than the square root of that number.

Comment: @Austin oh alright thanks

Answer (score 1):

The loop iterates on all numbers from 2 to the square root on `n`. For any divisor it could find above that square root (if it continued iterating to `n - 1`), there would obviously be another divisor below it.

Answer (score 1):

Because the [prime factorisation of any number `n` (by trial division) needs only check the prime numbers up to `sqrt(n)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division#Method)

> .. Furthermore, the trial factors need go no further than `sqrt(n)`
>   because, if `n` is divisible by some number `p`, then `n = p × q` and
>   if `q` were smaller than `p`, `n` would have been detected earlier as
>   being divisible by `q` or by a prime factor of `q`.

On a sidenote, trial division is slow to check for primality or possible primality. There are faster probabilistic tests like the [Miller-Rabin test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) which can check quickly if a number is composite or probably prime.

Comment: so if it can't find any divisors that  `n % divisor == 0` by the time it reaches the end of the range 2 till `sqrt(n)` then `n` is prime and it doesn't need to check further than that?

Comment: @CodingGrind, yes exactly